# Slow Database queries when on Secondary Node of Availability Group

Tags: query-performance, availability-groups, failover

Failover happens almost immediately, but an application connecting to several databases on the server runs WAY slower (Queries return in 4 minutes compared to 30 seconds).

The hardware and software on both is the same, both are patched and updated to the latest version of 2017. I have updated statistics too.

Any other suggestions as to why? Or how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Are you sure? I think statistics are replicated to secondary nodes. Take a look at this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-statistics-in-always-on-availability-groups/

Comment: @MBuschi Yep the last part of statement was not correct. Yes the bad query behavior can be due to outdated stats and yes stats are moved.

Comment: Anyway it's hard to guess with so few details. Can you compare and post execution plans of a query runned on both nodes?